# golang scanner read until end of reader

Tags: string, parsing, go

I have a bufio scanner on a StringReader. After I reach a certain line on the Scanner output, I want to read until the end of the reader. Is there any way to achieve this using a simpler way, other than the commented code ?

```
s := `1
2
3
4
5
6
7`

beyond5 := ""
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(s))
for scanner.Scan() {
    if strings.Contains(scanner.Text(), "5") {
        // Read all lines until EOF from scanner
        // and store in beyond5
        // for scanner.Scan() {
        //  beyond5 += scanner.Text()
        //  beyond5 += "\n"
        // }
        break
    }
}

log.Println(beyond5)
```

Comment: You can perhaps use a custom split function: https://play.golang.org/p/sr1pUIR3NC
However, this still may not perform complete seek to EOF and it doesn't split on `\n` anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems such an operation is not possible at all with the scanner. We need to use the bufio reader only. The code is:

```
s := `1
2
3
4
5
6
7`

beyond5 := ""
r := strings.NewReader(s)
reader := bufio.NewReader(r)
for {
    line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if strings.Contains(line, "5") {
        b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
        beyond5 = string(b)
        break
    }
}

log.Println(beyond5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this that you want? :-)

```
    s := `1
          2
          3
          4
          5
          6
          7`

    var beyond5 string

    if strings.Contains(s, "5") {
       scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(s))
       for scanner.Scan() {
          beyond5 += scanner.Text()
        }
    }

    beyond5 += "\n"

    log.Println(beyond5)
```

**UPDATE:** My solution is similar to @abhink's solution, however, they are different solutions

I have used [Split method](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Split), this method set split (private) property that it is [SplitFunc type](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#SplitFunc). And this is my implementation:

```
var canPass bool

func mySplit(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
    for pos, value := range data {

        if (value < '6' && !canPass) || (value < '0' || value > '9') {
            continue
        }

        canPass = true
        return pos+1, data[pos : pos + 1], nil
    }

    return 0, nil, nil
}
```

Now, you must use Split method, send it mySplit as parameter.

```
scanner.Split(mySplit)
```

And you do a simple for with `scanner.Scan()`

```
for scanner.Scan() {
        beyond5 += scanner.Text() + "\n"
}
```

Output:

```
6
7
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Sq6QaHchy5)

I hope it is the solution that you were looking for :-)

Comment: No. This is not what I want. I want "6\n7" to be printed. But more importantly, I want to know if there is a way to read until EOF from a scanner, from its SEEK_CUR position.

Comment: @SankarP, I have updated my solution. See **UPDATE**